# XML in SQL: Element values evaluated differently when using table column rather than string

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to generate some XML via SQL for load testing, but I'm having trouble constructing the XML correctly. This is what I have:

```
-- Generate XML from table
SELECT id AS '@id',
action AS '@action',
actionTime AS '@actionTime',
firstName AS '@firstName',
lastName AS '@lastName',
email AS '@email',
  (SELECT isActive AS '@isActive',
   actionTime AS '@actionTime',
   displayName AS '@displayName',
   identifierId 
FOR XML PATH('identifier'), TYPE
)
FROM scratch.dbo.Identities
FOR XML PATH('user'), ROOT('Users')
```

This generates XML that looks like this:

```
<Users>
   <user id="QALoadTest1" action="add" actionTime="2015-11-01T00:00:00" firstName="Load" lastName="Test1" email="QALoadTest1@loadtest.com">
     <identifier isActive="1" actionTime="2015-11-01T00:00:00" displayName="Load Test 1">
        <identifierId>1111111111</identifierId>
      </identifier>
    </user>
</Users>
```

If I pass a string as the identifier value, the XML is generated correctly:

```
SELECT id AS '@id',
action AS '@action',
actionTime AS '@actionTime',
firstName AS '@firstName',
lastName AS '@lastName',
email AS '@email',
  (SELECT isActive AS '@isActive',
   actionTime AS '@actionTime',
   displayName AS '@displayName',
   '11111111111' 
FOR XML PATH('identifier'), TYPE
)
FROM scratch.dbo.Identities
FOR XML PATH('user'), ROOT('Users')
```

This generates the following, which is what I want:

```
<Users>
   <user id="QALoadTest1" action="add" actionTime="2015-11-01T00:00:00" firstName="Load" lastName="Test1" email="QALoadTest1@loadtest.com">
     <identifier isActive="1" actionTime="2015-11-01T00:00:00" displayName="Load Test 1">11111111111</identifierId>
    </user>
</Users>
```

What's the difference between using a column value and a string here? Interestingly, when I wrap the column value in single quotes (`''' + identifierId + '''`) it generates the XML in the correct structure, but with the additional quote marks (`...displayName="Load Test 1">'11111111111'</identifierId>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hardcoded value doesn't generate a column name automatically; the column selection does (look at the difference in the header of the results between `SELECT identifierId from Identities` and `SELECT '11111111111' from Identities`.)

Try telling it that you specifically want your data in a text node rather than with a column-derived name:

```
-- Generate XML from table
SELECT id AS '@id',
action AS '@action',
actionTime AS '@actionTime',
firstName AS '@firstName',
lastName AS '@lastName',
email AS '@email',
  (SELECT isActive AS '@isActive',
   actionTime AS '@actionTime',
   displayName AS '@displayName',
   identifierId AS 'text()'
FOR XML PATH('identifier'), TYPE
)
FROM scratch.dbo.Identities
FOR XML PATH('user'), ROOT('Users')
```